# Сравнение Cocoa и Carbon

Tags: cocoa, carbon, mac

Сталкивались ли вы с Carbon? Что вы можете об этом сказать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carbon был создан для легкого перехода с и на Mac OS 8 и 9. Если ваш код должен работать под OS 8 или 9, тогда Carbon отличное решение. ([Источник](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_(API)))

Но, если ваше приложение разрабатывается для OS X, тогда вам стоит сделать упор на Cocoa, а не Carbon.

Также важным аргументом является портируемость на iPhone и, по-моему, только Cocoa API ее имеет.

Коротко можно сказать так:
Для новых приложений используйте Cocoa. некоторый код все еще может использовать Carbon и если вам не нужны никакие новые возможность, этот код может продолжать работать.

Cocoa имеет Objective-C API, а также к ней можно обращаться из C и C++ с легкостью. Carbon написан на чистом C. И Cocoa, и Carbon доступны через порты для многих других популярных языков, но обычно они имеют некоторые ограничения.